# How to add a form with a paperclip field in another view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

So as the title suggest, what Im trying to accomplish here is fairly simple. I need to generate a from in the `show` view of my controller. I have a devise generate user that I want to have a header image. However, instead of adding the `header_img` field to the devise form I want to just have it by itself in my view. Ultimately I want it where I click on a "Edit" button on my view it will show the form. Similar to how twitter does it. Right now I am getting an `undefined local variable or method users_path error`. I have followed the documentation on github for paperclip and Im not sure whats wrong.

***My Show View***

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="well well-sm">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1><%= @user.full_name %></h1>
      </div>

      <!-- show option only if curr user == show profile user -->
      <%= form_for @user, url: users_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| %>
        <%= form.file_field :header_img %>
      <% end %>

      <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', "#", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    #this is for the business header img
    has_attached_file :header_img, styles: { large: "1200x500>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :header_img, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with using paperclip fields on other views. 
The helper you are trying to use `users_path` will be available only if you declare a resourceful route.

From Rails Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

> Creating a resourceful route will also expose a number of helpers to the controllers in your application. In the case of resources :photos:

```
photos_path returns /photos
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
edit_photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

You must check if you declared a resourceful route for user model.

Hope this help.